# Backup tracker indexes (tracker index --backup)

Tags: gnome, files, backup, search, tracker

Sorry, I'd like to backup the tracker index before resetting it, does anyone know how to use $ tracker index --backup ?

I didn't find any examples on the net and I don't understand how to use it, $ man tracker-index says:
tracker index --backup 
Begins backing up the Tracker databases and save it to the file given.

But it doesn't accept me any kind of file (https://hastebin.com/hehodilube.yaml - translated in English with Google Translate: https://hastebin.com/tixedivebu.yaml), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Indicate the command you tried. The man page says `--backup=<file>`, so you need to supply a file name that indicates where to save the backup.

Comment: Hello @vanadium, in the hastebin links I wrote there are the commands I executed

Comment: Are the error messages not giving you any hints? Looks like you might need to supply an existing directory as the destination.

Comment: @vanadium it works neither with a directory nor with a normal file nor with a file with the .tar extension, as you can see in the hastebin